# QWidget with dynamic vertical but fixed horizontal size

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

My goal is to create a compound widget that contains a searchbox and a ListView. The view is going to dynamically adjust its vertical size due to filtering by a proxymodel (so it fit it's contents).
The compound widget should derive it's vertical size depending on contents, but allow users to resize the horizontal dimension.
I have found no way to achieve this behaviour using `sizePolicies` and `sizeContraints`, but maybe someone has more experience with Qt's confusing layout system.

Here is the code for an minimal reproducible example:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed
        )

        self.search_widget = SearchWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.search_widget)

class SearchWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SearchWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        self.search_edit = SearchBox()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.search_edit)  

        self.search_view = SearchView()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.search_view)

        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed
        )

class SearchBox(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SearchBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed
        )

class SearchView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SearchView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.max_items_to_display = 3

        self._model = QtCore.QStringListModel(["a", "b", "b2", "c"])
        self.setModel(self._model)

        self.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed
        )

        # must be set so that qabstractscroll area's sizehint() method doesn't default to some random size
        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)

    # must be overridden as there seems to be a default arbitrary minimumSizeHint() 
    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(-1,-1)

    def minimumSize(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(0,0)

    def viewportSizeHint(self):
        item_number = min(self.max_items_to_display, self.model().rowCount())
        total_width = super().viewportSizeHint().width()
        if item_number > 0:
            total_spacing = self.spacing() * item_number * 2 #empty space that is padded around an item in the layout. 
            total_height = sum(self.sizeHintForRow(i) for i in range(item_number)) + total_spacing
            return QtCore.QSize(total_width, total_height)
        else:
            return QtCore.QSize(total_width, 0)

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.model().rowCount() > 0:
            size = super(SearchView, self).sizeHint()
        else:
            size = QtCore.QSize(0, 0)
        return size
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = TestWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I do not understand your question, could you put images that illustrate what you want to obtain

Comment: TestWindow should have a fixed height (derived from it's child widgets) and should be horizontally resizeable